# Not sure of the equivelkent Golang tls client config for python. Not sure exactly about the ServerName key in tlsconfig

Tags: python, ssl, tls1.2

In this golang code the servername is set in the tlsclientconfig.
I'm not entirely sure how to do the equivlenet in python.
I couldn't find an equivelant in docs probably because I don't understand what I am searching haha

This is the config in GO, any tips on how I can set the servename in python, and what it exactly does in this case?

```golang
client := http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            ServerName: 'google.com'
    },
}
```

Comment: This could be called, "How can I use SNI in Python?" -- the meaning of ServerName is documented at https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#ClientHelloInfo

Comment: In general, if you're using the current version of `requests`, you don't need to do _anything_ to use SNI. It should Just Work, with no equivalent code needed, using the hostname from the URL you're trying to receive as the `ServerName`. If you have a situation where it doesn't work, as about _that specific situation_ with a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that was I was actually attempting to do was something called Domain Fronting.

A simple google search lead me to the correct configuration for python :)